# Function that returns non parameter functions

Tags: c#, functional-programming, functions

I found a function in c# like this:

```
  private Dictionary<string, Func<string>> ObtenerExtraCfgCampo(MsgDefCamp camp)
    {
        var extra = new Dictionary<string, Func<string>>();
        extra.Add("Oddity", () => camp.Order % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd");
        extra.Add("Odd", () => camp.Order % 2 == 0 ? "Odd" : string.Empty);
        extra.Add("Even", () => camp.Order % 2 != 0 ? "Even" : string.Empty);
        extra.Add("MsgPath", () => campo.MsgPath);
        return extra;

    }
```

Is there any utility on this? wouldn't it be better like this

```
private Dictionary<string, string> ObtenerExtraCfgCampo(MsgDefCamp camp)
{
    var extra = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    extra.Add("Oddity",  camp.Order % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd");
    extra.Add("Odd",  camp.Order % 2 == 0 ? "Odd" : string.Empty);
    extra.Add("Even",  camp.Order % 2 != 0 ? "Even" : string.Empty);
    extra.Add("MsgPath",  campo.MsgPath);
    return extra;

}
```

I undestand that changing camp would change the behavior of the functions. But isn't it too riski and difficult to reason about? 
I wonder if I'm missing the point of this

Comment: Instead of thinking of `Func<T>` as a *function that returns a T*, instead mentally think of it as `ComputedOnDemand<T>`.  A string is a string.  A `ComputedOnDemand<string>` is a thing that can compute a string when asked. Those are different!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ignoring the slight differences in type, interacting with the result of the first gives you a view onto the *current* state of `camp`, but the second gives a view onto *some previous* state of `camp` (I.E. when `ObtenerExtraCfgCampo` was called, probably billions of nanoseconds ago).

They do different things, so are not interchangeable. It's not any more risky than any other reference to mutable state.

I've just gone through most of an app changing a bunch of `Dictionary<Whatever, string>`s to `Dictionary<Whatever, Func<string>>`s so that we can change language at runtime

Comment: the difference in type actually tells you this as well

Comment: @jk not strictly, but it's a strong hint. I've just gone through most of an app changing a bunch of `Dictionary<Whatever, string>`s to `Dictionary<Whatever, Func<string>>`s so that we can change language at runtime

Comment: @Caleth the Language example that you just said has open my eyes in the ussefullness of this :D

Answer (score 3):

To see what the point of it is, try running the two versions of the method with mutating data, [eg see here for an example of what happens](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

The first version, using `Func` involves a closure over the `MsgDefCamp` instance. In other words, when the dictionary is interrogated it gets the current value, so in my example, it reports "Even" even though the value was off when the method was called.

The second version evaluates the contents of the `MsgDefCamp` instance when the method is called and stores those results in the dictionary. So even though the `Order` changes, the dictionary's value doesn't change and "Odd" is reported.

It can be difficult to reason *if you aren't familiar with such code*. It is an incredibly useful language feature though, so it's worth becoming familiar with it.

Comment: On you example, seems that changing both after declaration it stills changes it's value. I would asume that changing msgDefCamp2 would not change the result.

Comment: @AdrianGodoy, my apologies. That was very sloppy of me. I saw the results I was expecting so didn't proof-read the code and so posted a link to nonsense code. I've fixed it and updated the link.